# Cannot open Arelle menu view to use SEC's EdgarRenderer

Tags: xbrl, arelle

I have installed Arelle through git and using master branch.
Further on I am looking to use "SEC's EdgarRenderer" and made a git clone (also from it's master branch).
I copied in the EdgarRenderer folder structure into location of Arelle/plugins/EdgarRendered and selected the plugin from Arelle.

...after reload of Arelle, (recommended by the GUI) I do not see the window menu for "view", thus I cannot start to view a iXBRL document from a browser. Still the plugin shows status enabled.

From terminal session from where I triggered Arelle to open, I do see an error:

```
Exception loading plug-in Edgar Renderer: No module named 'matplotlib'
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Issue solved by loading the module 'matplotlib'